# Vue.js 2 component not displaying data

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to make a simple vue component work:

```
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>

<script>
  Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: '<div>A custom component! {{ xstr }} aa</div>',
    data: function() {
      return {
        xstr: 'i really want this to be visible',
      };
    }
  });

  window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  });
</script>
```

But apparently xstr is not displayed. What am I missing?

Comment: This code works, create **non-working** demo.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I identified my issue, but it's not related to vue. I used jinja2 for generating the html, and since jinja uses the {{ }} syntax for templating as well, the two systems interfered.